# Can the startup/splash screen be changed depending upon the state of the application upon startup?

Tags: ios

My app has a registration screen that is only presented once, and after registration is completed it is never shown again.

If my startup screen is a screenshot of the app then I would need to provide two screenshots and for the correct one to be initially displayed when the app launches.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, it is not currently possible. You cannot access the Default.png (or whatever you've named it instead) from your app to update it.

If it were me, I would set the startup screen to the one that is appropriate long term. You could also theoretically update your registration screen to be a bit closer to the look and feel of the main app screen, so it isn't so far off visually.